# How to read CDATA elements using karate dsl

Tags: dsl, karate

My XML request looks something like this :

- def ref = ref.substring(0, end)

```
  <ns:complete>

     <ns:identifier>23265</ns:identifier>

     <ns:taskData><![CDATA[<sch:SubscriptionApprovalResponse xmlns:sch="http://workflow.subscription.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org">

    <sch:status>APPROVED</sch:status>

    <sch:workflowExternalRef>#(ref)</sch:workflowExternalRef>

    <sch:description></sch:description>

    </sch:SubscriptionApprovalResponse>]]></ns:taskData>

  </ns:complete>
```

I am passing #(ref) from outside in the CDATA body but it's not reading it.

Is there something wrong that i am doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because you are trying to use embedded expressions in a `CDATA` section. I can't say without a full working example.

You should do this in 2 steps or use a string `replace`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace

```
* def baz = 'blah'
* def foo = <bar>#(baz)</bar>
* def xml = <foo><Response><![CDATA[#(foo)]]></Response></foo>
* match xml == <foo><Response><![CDATA[<bar>blah</bar>]]></Response></foo>

* def xml = <foo><Response><![CDATA[<bar>@@baz@@</bar>]]></Response></foo>
* replace xml.@@baz@@ = 'blah'
* match xml == <foo><Response><![CDATA[<bar>blah</bar>]]></Response></foo>
```